# Android barchart legends on top of the chart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

So i have a barchart in MPandroid, and i need to put the names on the chart, but there is no space where i want them, the solution is to put them on top of the chart. Like this:

[image: Red line where i want the text to be]

can someone help me achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in way of putting the text in a non-standard location, but you can do it by writing a custom renderer for your chart. If you extend the [`HorizontalBarChartRenderer`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/HorizontalBarChartRenderer.java) class and override the `drawValues` method (making just a few modifications to the original version in the code linked) you can change where the label gets drawn.

**Custom Renderer**

*Code copied from `drawValues` in [`HorizontalBarChartRenderer`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/HorizontalBarChartRenderer.java) and simplified to only include required parts for this use-case (removed logic for stacked charts, icons, toggling values on and off, etc). The only change is to the x,y values passed to `drawValue()`*

```java
private static class MyRenderer extends HorizontalBarChartRenderer {
    public MyRenderer(BarDataProvider chart, ChartAnimator animator,
                                      ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawValues(Canvas c) {

        List<IBarDataSet> dataSets = mChart.getBarData().getDataSets();

        final float valueOffsetPlus = Utils.convertDpToPixel(5f);

        for (int i = 0; i < mChart.getBarData().getDataSetCount(); i++) {

            IBarDataSet dataSet = dataSets.get(i);
            
            // apply the text-styling defined by the DataSet
            applyValueTextStyle(dataSet);
            ValueFormatter formatter = dataSet.getValueFormatter();

            // get the buffer
            BarBuffer buffer = mBarBuffers[i];

            for (int j = 0; j < buffer.buffer.length * mAnimator.getPhaseX(); j += 4) {
                
                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsTop(buffer.buffer[j + 1]))
                    break;

                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsX(buffer.buffer[j]))
                    continue;

                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsBottom(buffer.buffer[j + 1]))
                    continue;

                BarEntry entry = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(j / 4);
                String formattedValue = formatter.getBarLabel(entry);

                // Modify the x, y position here to control where the
                // text is. The "buffer" array gives the positions of
                // the current bar (in pixels)
                drawValue(c,
                        formattedValue,
                        buffer.buffer[j] + valueOffsetPlus,
                        buffer.buffer[j+1] - valueOffsetPlus,
                        dataSet.getValueTextColor(j / 2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Use**

To use the custom renderer, set it on the chart and modify the bar widths to leave room for the text.

```java
HorizontalBarChart chart = findViewById(R.id.chart);

List<Float> values = Arrays.asList(3f, 2f, 2.2f);
List<Integer> colors = Arrays.asList(Color.CYAN, Color.RED, Color.GREEN);
List<String> labels = Arrays.asList("Pickled Horses", "Horses", "Pickles");

List<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i) {
    entries.add(new BarEntry(i+1, values.get(i), labels.get(i)));
}

BarDataSet ds = new BarDataSet(entries, "Values");
ds.setColors(colors);
ds.setValueTextSize(14f);
ds.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getBarLabel(BarEntry barEntry) {
        return (String)barEntry.getData();
    }
});
ds.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);

BarData data = new BarData(ds);

// Reduce bar width to leave room for text
data.setBarWidth(0.75f);

// Use the custom renderer
chart.setRenderer(new MyRenderer(chart, chart.getAnimator(), chart.getViewPortHandler()));

// Misc formatting & setup
chart.setData(data);
chart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
chart.getAxisRight().setAxisMinimum(0f);
chart.getAxisRight().setAxisMaximum(4f);
chart.getAxisRight().setGranularity(1f);
chart.getAxisRight().setTextSize(14f);
chart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
chart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(false);
chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
chart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(3.6f);
chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
chart.setBorderColor(Color.BLACK);
chart.setBorderWidth(1f);
chart.setDrawBorders(true);
```

[image: example output]

Comment: That was a "hell" of a help. Much appreciated !!!! Thanks

Comment: one thing that isnt working for me, is that i cant get my string label, it always put my count of items. like instead of horses i got the number of horses (2)

Comment: You need a custom ValueFormatter like I used. Check the code in my answer. I add the label as the "data" attribute in BarEntry and read that in the ValueFormatter (`BarEntry(x,y,label)` and `getBarLabel`)